# pq a iteração do x do input NÃO interfere na iteração do x do loop while, sendo que é a mesma variável?

Tags: python-3.x, loop, while, iterator

estou aprendendo lógica de programação com o Python e não entendo como o x do input NÃO interfere na iteração do x do loop while, sendo que é a mesma variável. Por favor, gostaria que me explicassem, valew!!!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

numeros = [0,0,0,0,0]

x = 0

while x < 5: 
    numeros[x] = int(input("Números %d:" %(x + 1) )) 
    x += 1

while True:
    escolhido = int(input("Que posição você quer imprimir (0 para sair): "))
    if escolhido == 0:
        break
    print("Você escolheu o número: %d" %( numeros[escolhido -1] ))
```

Comment: que `x` do `input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando você faz qualquer operação com uma variável, ela não muda de valor.

```
x = 1
x + 1 // 2
print(x) // 1
```

Para alterar o valor de uma variável você precisa atribuir um novo valor para ela.

```
x = 1
print(x) // 1
x = x + 1 // mesmo que x += 1
print(x) // 2
```

Por isso só o segundo `x` é que altera o valor. Porque no primeiro ele simplesmente retorna o valor somado mas não altera o valor original da variável por não ter nenhuma atribuição.